# Unable to get the value of 'xml:lang' attribute

Tags: xslt

```
<xoe:documents xmlns:xoe="http://xxxxxx" count="1">

  <xocs:doc xmlns:xocs="xxxxxx" xmlns:xsi="yyyyyyy" xsi:schemaLocation="zzzzzz">

    <xocs:meta>...</xocs:meta>

    <xocs:serial-item>
      <!-- this line -->
      <article xmlns:sa="www.google.hgy" xmlns="http://www.xyzq1.org/xml/ja/dtd" version="5.4" xml:lang="pl" docsubtype="rev">
        <article-info>
        </article-info>
      </article>

    </xocs:serial-item>

  </xocs:doc>

</xoe:documents>
```

I am unable to get the value of 'xml:lang' attribute. Even thought I tried with the below xpath

```
<xsl:variable name="rootPath" select="/xoe:documents/xocs:doc/xocs:serial-item"/>
<xsl:variable name="lang" select="$rootPath/ja:article[@xml:lang]"/>
or 
<xsl:variable name="lang" select="$rootPath/ja:article/@xml:lang"/>
```

here ja is already defined in my xslt code

```
xmlns:ja="http://www.xyzq1.org/xml/ja/dtd"
```

Can some one please help?

Comment: In your example XML, `article` is in the `www.yahoo.mkt` namespace, not `http://www.xyzq1.org/xml/ja/dtd`.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it. Still no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare these:

```
xmlns:xoe="http://xxxxxx"
xmlns:xocs="xxxxxx"
xmlns:ya="www.yahoo.mkt"
```

Then you can get the value of the `xml:lang` attribute using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/xoe:documents/xocs:doc/xocs:serial-item/ya:article/@xml:lang"/>
```

---

Note that the URIs in your stylesheet namespace declarations must be the same URIs that appear in your source XML. The prefixes can be anything you like.

Comment: yes , I have everything in my code as you recommended. But still I'm unable to get the value.

Comment: @AJAYKUMAR You can see it working (adapted to your modified example) here: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAK

Comment: Even I have some tags inside <aricle-info>, I can get the values of those. But I'm unable to get the value of any attribute in <article> tag.

Comment: @AJAYKUMAR We can only answer based on what you provide in your question.

Comment: For example:<xsl:value-of select="/xoe:documents/xocs:doc/xocs:serial-item//ya:article-info/ya:jid"/> I am getting values for this.  And I forgot to tell this <article> tag is not same for all xmls, it can be in different names based on  the different article. Will this  make any impact? But for the current scenario I'm working now is having <article> tag only.

Comment: @AJAYKUMAR We can only answer based on what you provide in your question.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll try

Comment: The answer you provided is perfect. Sorry I have troubled you. Actually the xml we are using in background and the xml is shown to us are differnt. In the background there are no attributes for <article> tag. That is why I was unable to get the value. Thank you so much. @michael.hor257k